# Model first vs Data first in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-model-first

Which one should I choose for new project? Could I assume, that data-first model provides better DB performance, and model-first provides better OOP handling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you a vague answer I'm sure.. But it depends.

If you are primarily responsible for end to end design development and implementation, including the database, then go with what you are most comfortable. In that situation, I tend to go model first, but that's because that's how I think. I've also worked with a team where the database model was developed first, and obviously, that dictates db first.

Answer (score 0):

This does depend.  If its more data driven, I would go data model first. to If its more data driven, I would go data first.

If its about equal I go data driven first. I usually get the requirements, and then create a database model from that, then my model with utilize the database the meet the requirements.

Comment: can I recommend you change this sentence `If its more data driven, I would go data model first.` to `If its more data driven, I would go data first.` for clarity sake?

Answer (score 0):

imho Model first gives you less resistance. You'll get quicker up to speed and if needed you can optimize what you actually need.

Letting the code drive the needs while you iteratively implement different scenarios, should result in a storage model that's more appropriate for the operations that you need.